# SQL Server Where [column] <>

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

This is probably something daft, so I'll apologise in advance.

Say I have two tables:

```
|    TABLE 1    |    |      TABLE 2      |
-----------------     ---------------------
|RESULT | REASON|    |ID    | DESCRIPTION|
-----------------    ---------------------
|  1    | NULL  |    | A    | NO INTEREST|
|  2    |   A   |    | B    | CALL CLOSED|
|  2    |   B   |    | C    | DECEASED   |
|  1    | NULL  |    ---------------------
-----------------
```

So, `REASON` can only have a value if the `RESULT` is 2. Otherwise it is `NULL`.

Now suppose I run the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.RESULT, t2.DESCRIPTION
FROM
    [TABLE 1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [TABLE 2] t2 ON t1.RESULT = t2.ID
```

We would get the following:

```
------------------------
| RESULT | DESCRIPTION |
------------------------
|   1    |     NULL    |
|   2    | NO INTEREST |
|   2    | CALL CLOSED |
|   1    |     NULL    | 
------------------------
```

Now what I have found is that if I then add a WHERE clause like so:

```
SELECT
    t1.RESULT, t2.DESCRIPTION
FROM
    [TABLE 1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [TABLE 2] t2 ON t1.RESULT = t2.ID
WHERE
    t2.DESCRIPTION <> 'CALL CLOSED'
```

I for some reason end up with the following:

```
------------------------
| RESULT | DESCRIPTION |
------------------------   
|   2    | NO INTEREST |
------------------------
```

Adding the where clause would seem to exclude all the records with result 1 ergo, all the records with NULL reason values/description values.

Am I missing something daft here?

Comment: Any comparison with `NULL` yields "undefined". So neither `NULL = 'CALL CLOSED' nor 'NULL <> 'CALL CLOSED'` is true. If you want to include NULL values, use `<> 'CALL CLOSED' OR t2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL`

Comment: probably because left join won't find a t2 row to join so it cannot make the comparison.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but did you mean `ON t1.REASON = t2.ID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL` is not an "empty value" or something like that, it is a lack of a value - any operation on it which expects a value will return **unknown**.
Since unknown is not true, every row evaluated for a condition returning unknown in the `where` clause will not be returned in the query.

Think of your condition using the `<>` operator as asking "does description have a value that is different than 'CALL CLOSED'" - the answer is no, since it doesn't have a value at all.

Once we've established that, handling it is simple - just check for `NULL` explicitly:

```
SELECT
    t1.RESULT, t2.DESCRIPTION
FROM
    [TABLE 1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [TABLE 2] t2 ON t1.RESULT = t2.ID
WHERE
    t2.DESCRIPTION IS NULL OR t2.DESCRIPTION <> 'CALL CLOSED'
```

Comment: "any operation on it which expects a value will return false." - this is incorrect. `NULL`s force the third truth value, `UNKNOWN`. This can easily be demonstrated by e.g. doing `NOT (Description <> 'CALL CLOSED')` - if `Description <> 'CALL CLOSED'` returned `false` for the `NULL`, then the `NOT` should force that condition to be true. This is not so.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are correct, I over simplified things, to the point of incorrectness. Edited my post to be more accurate. BTW, thanks for the `NOT` example - quite an elegant way of explaining things!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid losing the TABLE 1 rows, you can add the TABLE 2 filter predicate in the LEFT JOIN condition instead:

```
SELECT
    t1.RESULT, t2.DESCRIPTION
FROM
    [TABLE 1] t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [TABLE 2] t2 ON t1.RESULT = t2.ID AND t2.DESCRIPTION <> 'CALL CLOSED'
```

This way you express that you want all rows from TABLE 1, and the DESCRIPTION from TABLE 2 when the TABLE 2 row matches the join condition.